# Gap between Images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I just got inspired and tried to recreate an effect I have seen on Codrops, but now I am stuck. Between my images is a small gap which is not going away even when I set the margin and the padding to 0.
[Here is a CodePen with my problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvrMKm)

I would be grateful if someone could help me. Thank you!

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvrMKm
```

Comment: no gap here, which browser?

Comment: no gap on chrome. which browser are you testing this?

Comment: The gap is there on chrome, scroll down the page on codepen

Comment: I am using Chrome. Just for anyone who is interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the images to have a block value:

```
figure img {
  display:block;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYvNzg)

Comment: Thank you! Works great now. What is the normal display mode of an image? I always thought it was block already.

Comment: You're welcome. I think most browsers provide a default value of `inline-block`.

Comment: A. Wolff: You have to add it in the codePen to see the changes. It is not added in the link.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `font-size: 0` to parent `ul` and set the desire one in child `li` elements like:

```
ul {
  font-size: 0;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

This happens because in `inline` elements white space between them become actual space in html.

[**codepen**](http://codepen.io/Chariz/pen/zxdgmr)

Comment: You are right, I just tired it and it works, too. But I think Tony Barnes' answer is a bit easier and therefore I will use his solution. But thank you anyways.